# Unable to catch Cartalyst \ Sentinel \ Checkpoints \ NotActivatedException in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, acl

Im learning how to use Cartalyst/Sentinel.

I've

1) Installed Laravel and imported the package. Run migrations and generated necessary tables.
2) I've created the the user registration form and controller that

1. Creates a record
2. Creates activation code
3. Sends the user an email with an activation link.

If a user activates by clicking the link, they are able to sign in.

If they don't activate they can't (which is what i want).

My issue is i have the following method that tries to catch if there is a NotActivatedException. I want to redirect the user to the home page that alerts the user that this account is not activated. But i get the Laravel error message rather than my view that displays the error. Here's my code.

public function postSignin() {

```
try {

    // Validation
    $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validation->fails()) {
        return Redirect::route('signin')->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
    }

    $remember = (Input::get('remember') == 1) ? true : false;

    if ($user = Sentinel::authenticate(Input::all(), $remember)) {
        return Redirect::route('home')->with('global', 'Howdy ' . $user->username . '!');
    }

    $errors = 'Invalid Email / Password';

    return Redirect::route('signin')->with('global', $errors);

} catch (NotActivatedException $e) {

    $errors = 'Account not activated.';

    return Redirect::route('signin')->with('global', $errors);

}

return Redirect::route('home')->with('global', 'There was a problem signing you in.');

}
```

Im not sure why the catch is not working as i'd like to display the signin page with the error that states 'Account not activated'. Instead i get the Laravel debug page that looks like this.

[image]

Comment: Try adding `use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Checkpoints\NotActivatedException;` at the top of your controller file.

Comment: Thank you :) Will i have to do this for all my controllers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the full class name:

```
catch (\Cartalyst\Sentinel\Checkpoints\NotActivatedException $e)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also add `use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Checkpoints\NotActivatedException;` at the top of your controller file to be able to access it without using the full class name.

Do this in each controller that mentions `NotActivatedException`.